ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input. for this code 'inputs=model.input'
This is the code of a CNN model which I'm using to generate human images with size of 124x124 pixels:

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_samples, PARAM_SIZE, input_shape = (1,)))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Flatten(name='pre_encoder'))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Reshape((PARAM_SIZE, 1, 1), name='encoder'))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 4))           #(4, 4)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides = 2))                #(10,10)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, 4))                #(13, 13)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, 4, strides = 2))                #(28,28)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, 6, strides = 2))                #(60,60)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(3, 6, strides = 2))                #(124,124)
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
print (model.output_shape)
    
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

func = Model(inputs = model.get_layer('encoder').input, outputs = model.layers[-1].output)
enc_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                  outputs=model.get_layer('pre_encoder').output)

but I'm getting this error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 # model.layers[-1].output
----> 2 model.input

File D:\Program_files\envs\btp_project\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py:228, in Operation.input(self)
    218 @property
    219 def input(self):
    220     """Retrieves the input tensor(s) of a symbolic operation.
    221 
    222     Only returns the tensor(s) corresponding to the *first time*
   (...)
    226         Input tensor or list of input tensors.
    227     """
--> 228     return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(0, "input_tensors", "input")

File D:\Program_files\envs\btp_project\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py:259, in Operation._get_node_attribute_at_index(self, node_index, attr, attr_name)
    243 """Private utility to retrieves an attribute (e.g. inputs) from a node.
    244 
    245 This is used to implement the properties:
   (...)
    256     The operation's attribute `attr` at the node of index `node_index`.
    257 """
    258 if not self._inbound_nodes:
--> 259     raise ValueError(
    260         f"The layer {self.name} has never been called "
    261         f"and thus has no defined {attr_name}."
    262     )
    263 if not len(self._inbound_nodes) > node_index:
    264     raise ValueError(
    265         f"Asked to get {attr_name} at node "
    266         f"{node_index}, but the operation has only "
    267         f"{len(self._inbound_nodes)} inbound nodes."
    268     )

ValueError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input.

Please help me with this...
Here I'm trying to build a model to generate human images with image size of 124x124 pixels, please help me with this if anyone knows...
